# iOS EventKit - Access My App From Calendar

Tags: ios, calendar, eventkit

I have read the Calendars and Reminders Programming Guide, as well as the EventKit and related framework references, however have been unable to find the answer to my question - unless of course the answer is "it is not possible".

My question is this: If I allow users of my app to create calendar events from within the app, is it possible for the user to be sent to my app after tapping on the event (within the calendar app)?

Comment: If you want to add events or Reminders to Iphone Calendar from any sender event then you are always in application.

Comment: @yourwish - I realise that, you have obviously misread my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you can't have the Calendar App redirect to your App when the user opens the Event. However, you can probably drop a link in the description of the event, and clicking on that link will open your app using Custom URL Schemes.

Here's a link to the reference documentation on creating [Custom URL Schemes](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/AdvancedAppTricks/AdvancedAppTricks.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50).

Comment: Apple uses this mechanism to link Events to the Mail Messages from which they were created, see details at [cultofmac](http://www.cultofmac.com/248061/mail-messages-now-have-linkable-clickable-urls-in-ios-7/)

Answer (score 0):

Sadly not. This is a typical example of application sandbagging. You can send stuff out when Apple provides a framework to do so but you can't go the other way. This is by the way one of the core difference between iOS and Android.

Comment: Uninformed bias much? The Custom URL scheme solution isn't as integrated as I'd prefer, but clearly it *is* possible.